# JavaScript Constants - Defining Multiple Functions

Tags: javascript, constants

I've been trying to get multiple functions working in 1 `const`, but it either does not work (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`) or I'm  missing something, and I hope someone can help.

Why does this work:

```
const dynamicresponse = {
    login(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
}
```

And why does this not work?

```
const dynamicresponse = {
    login(response) {
        alert(response);
    }

    adminsearchuser(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
}
```

And is there a way to get the example above working?

Comment: `{ login(response) { ... } }` is shorthand for `{ login: function() { ... } }` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)). As _@connexo_ already mentioned, you're missing commas and therefore get a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the body of your `login()` method.

```js
const dynamicresponse = {
    login(response) {
        alert(response);
    },

    adminsearchuser(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
}

dynamicresponse.login('foo')
dynamicresponse.adminsearchuser('foo')
```

The notation you tried is used on Javascript `class` objects.

Comment: I knew I was probably missing something, but did not know there needs to be a comma at the end. This fixed my issue, thanks!